# "Wise man" vs. "wise guy"

Tags: etymology, differences, word-usage, origin-unknown

Two very similar expressions yet quite opposite connotations. *Wise man* is an older phrase but *wise guy* is a newer one.

I found two possible connections to *wise man*. There is the surname *Wiseman* which is a long-established surname of Anglo-Saxon origin, and derives from the Olde English pre 7th Century "wys", meaning "wise", and "mann", a man, and was originally given as a nickname to a wise and learned man, perhaps one who was regularly consulted by other village inhabitants on matters pertaining to law or business transactions.<sup>1</sup>

*Wise men* is also mentioned as another name for *biblical magi* who were, in the Gospel of Matthew and Christian tradition, a group of distinguished foreigners who visited Jesus after his birth, bearing gifts of gold, frankincense and myrrh.<sup>2</sup>

Opposite connotations of the words from [*thefreedictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wise+man):

> *wise man*:  a sage / a wise and trusted guide and advisor
>
> ---
>
> *wise guy:* a smart aleck / a person who is given to making conceited, sardonic, or insolent comments

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wise) says:

> *Wise man* was in Old English. *Wise guy* is attested from 1896, American English...

- How do these two phrases happen to have different connotations (one positive, other negative)?
- Is it possible to find an explanation regarding to their origins?

---

<sub>1 http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Wiseman</sub> 
<sub>2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Magi</sub>

Comment: '''as do 'smart cookie' and 'smart aleck'.

Comment: I've heard "smart cookie" used both straight and sarcastically, but "smart aleck" only sarcastically.

Comment: Because language is unpredictable.

Comment: You [are not the first](http://www.fairfaxchristmaslights.com/images/3wiseguys.jpg) to ask this question.

Comment: [*Oh, a wise guy, eh?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yscaDkzHqek)

Comment: Noting that American English is cited above as the origin of the expression, I wonder if there might be a connection between the term and America's traditional distrust of intellectuals among a significant portion of the populace. I've been trying to look for equivalents in other languages, particularly in my native language, Spanish. We have the word "sabiondo" which means a know it all. The implication is that he doesn't know it all. Maybe the same but also maybe a shade of difference. I think the Spanish-speaking world may also be guilty of a touch of anti intellectualism. This is a very in

Comment: I seem to recall "wise guy" being a euphemism for a criminal, particularly a mobster.

Answer (score 6):

The "wise" in "wise guy" is sarcastic. The surface meaning of "wise guy" is synonymous to "wise man," but in actual usage "wise guy" ALWAYS refers to someone who is making a sardonic comment, implying that he (thinks he) is somehow smarter than others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how did "wise guy" emerge as a sarcastic usage? Why not "wise man" itself used sarcastically? Is it related to the difference between "man" and "guy" also?

Comment: That would be my *guess* - that the tone of "guy" is dissonant with the whole idea of "wise," and so using the phrase "wise guy" conveys sarcasm. But that seems like a pretty sophisticated research question to me.

Comment: And let's not forget the "wise guy" that is another name for a mob thug.

Comment: 'Guy' has long been used in America as a convivial term for 'man' and nowadays 'woman'. The sense is far more recent in Britain. For me, a 'Guy' is  an effigy of Guido Fawkes, Roman Catholic conspirator at the centre of the Gunpowder Plot, to blow up Parliament, of 1605. Every 5th November children throw his effigy on bonfires and celebrate with firworks. That will always remain with me the principal association with the word 'guy'. 'Always remember the fifth of November/For gunpowder, treason and plot/ I see no reason/ Why gunpowder season/ Should ever be forgot. (Children's rhyme)

Comment: I'd suggest that 'guy' is/was just more commonly used than 'man'. Therefore 'wise guy' would be used more than 'wise man', and thus it would be more susceptible to semantic change. As 'wise guy' was more and more commonly used sarcastically to imply the opposite, speakers would have no choice but to reach back and use the less colloquial 'wise man' to differentiate. All conjecture, of course.

Comment: Don't forget *wise ass*, *wiseacre*, and *weisenheimer*.

Comment: "Man" has somewhat more of a connotation of having earned respect than "guy" does.  Or, in Dave Barry's terms, "men went to the moon, but guys invented mooning."

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that "digital computing" doesn't mean counting on your fingers. English expressions grow out of usage, not logic or etymology.

Comment: More examples along the same lines: "terrific" vs. "terrible"; "awesome" vs. "awful"; and, if you're willing to accept etymologies from Greek and Latin simultaneously, "chronic" vs. "temporary".

Answer (score 1):

An etymological explanation might be that the word *wise* is related to the word *wit*. (The OED traces both back to the Indo-European root *weid-*.) One sense of *wit* is a synonym of wisdom or intelligence, but the other sense is "a talent for banter or persiflage" (see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wit). So, perhaps the sense of *wise* as in *wise guy*, *wiseacre*, *crack wise*, etc., can be thought of as essentially a variation on this sense of *wit*. In other words, what are now two words are still not perfectly differentiated.